# error when trying to run RDAVIDWebService

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm trying to run RDAVIDWebService:

```
library("RDAVIDWebService")
e_mail <- 'myemail.org'
david<-DAVIDWebService$new(email = e_mail,
                           url =  'https://david.ncifcrf.gov/webservice/services/DAVIDWebService.DAVIDWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/' )
```

and I'm getting this error

> [INFO] Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://david.ncifcrf.gov/webservice/services/DAVIDWebService.DAVIDWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection or outbound has closed Error in .jcall(stub, "S", "authenticate", email) : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection or outbound has closed

I followed the instructions given in stackoverflow and biocsupport but still getting the same error.

When I type `java -version` in my terminal:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_272-8u272-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)
```

And this in R:

```
> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
[1] 0
> .jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")
[1] "1.8.0_272-8u272-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04-b10"
```

Am I doing something wrong?